# Data structure for Railway routes

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

What is the good data structure for railway routes. I have information about all the trains, what all stations they are passing through. Given two stations, I need to come up with all possible paths.

I came up with a graph where key is the start station and an adjacency list represents the stations it is passing through.

But I think this will not give me correct answer .

Comment: What is your actual question? Are you looking for an algorithm to compute the fastest route? Just a data structure to capture the problem? Are you concerned primarily with efficiency or ease-of-implementation?

Comment: @bitmask "I need to come up with all possible paths"

Comment: Why don't you think a graph search will give you the correct answer? If you could elaborate your reasons, people would be able to help you much more precisely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a straight-forward graph problem, and (to me) modelling the way the railwork network actually looks with the graph sounds intuitive.

That is, have a graph node for each station, with edges representing railway connections between them.

The problem then becomes a graph search, for which there are plenty of algorithms to choose from.

Answer (score 3):

First, you have the railway network: this is very naturally expressed as stations being the nodes in a graph and railway links being the edges, which connect the nodes.

Second, you have the trains, or, put it another way, the lines. This is most naturally expressed as a set of paths through the above graph, each path corresponding to a different train.

I assume that you need all the possible routes in the form of

> Take train T1 at station S0, travel to station S1, switch to train T2, travel to S2, etc... arrive at destination.

In such a case, I'd model both the railway network and the trains in a single multi- graph structure, with multiple edges leading from station `Sn` to station `Sm`, each edge corresponding to different train which passes from `Sn` to `Sm`. The structure for this would be a set of nodes, each node having a list of outgoing edges.

Then perform a simple depth first search, with marking individual edges to make sure you don't traverse an edge twice, like in the following generator pseudocode:

```
// path is a list of edges
// src,dst are nodes

procedure generate_route (path, src, dst)
  if src == dst
    yield path
  else
    for e in all outgoing edges of src
      if e is not visited
         mark e as visited
         generate_route (path + e, e.dst, dst)
```